# Custom Emoji Discordjs v12 returning undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js, emoji

I am trying to get a custom emoji using discordjs v12, and I want to make it so that no matter what server the bot is in, it will be able to send the custom emoji. Here is my code b

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'showemoji',
    description: 'shows my cool custom emoji!',
    cooldown: 0,
    execute(message, args, d) {
        const someEmoji = message.client.emojis.cache.get("778264742606798860");
        message.channel.send(`${someEmoji}`);
    }
};
```

However, when it is sent in chat, it says 'undefined', and it throws no errors in the console. How do I fix this?

Comment: By the way, the id is valid.

Comment: Have you tried logging `message.client.emojis.cache` to see if the emojis are there?

Comment: No, I'll try it however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your bot is in the server with the emoji, you can simply use

```
// Checks if the bot has permission to user external emojis
if (message.guild.me.permissions.has('USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS')) {
    message.channel.send('<:EMOJI_NAME:778264742606798860>');
}
```

If you're code isn't finding the emoji in the cache, there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Whenever I try to use that however, it just prints :EMOJI_NAME: instead of the actual emoji

Comment: Have you replaced :EMOJI_NAME: with the name of your emoji?

Comment: Yes, I have, it just e.g <:silver:778290144272056360>, prints :silver:

Comment: Oh my goodness! I just found the error, it turns out I was copying the wrong ID, silly me! Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Haha, no problem